# PHP translation not always working

Tags: php, android, google-chrome, emoji

I have been trying to make a website which turns all the characters in a sentence to an emoji beginning with that letter (I got very bored)

Here is my code

[image]

Sorry I couldn't add this as text, it kept running even when set as code

Anyway, it works on some devices but not others

Windows 10 Chrome:
[image]

Android Marshmallow Chrome
[image]

Is there any reason why this happens, and if so how can I fix this?

This is hosted [here](http://samrobbins.125mb.com/emoji)

Comment: Try setting the character set to UTF8 for the doc. If you add the code to the question might be able to help you better.

Comment: Ah, character encoding issues ... the programmers' Achilles Heel.  Perhaps start with a charset declaration in the HTML?  What charset does the server think it's serving?  And what charsets are best suited for emoji work?  I really don't know much about those ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

To the head of the website

Thanks chris85 for the comment